# Adjust for Subtotals in Raw Data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-munging

This is a typical problem for congressional budget analysts working with [messy data](https://budget.dtic.mil/spreadsheets/FY2019_spreadsheets/HASC/Combined_OM.xlsx).

Dataframe shows amounts requested and authorized for each item.

The authorized amount is sometimes more or less than the amount requested. When this happens, adjustments (with explanatory text not included here) are shown in brackets below a total.

For example, in the dataframe below, authorizors adjusted the requested amount for item "a" `(80 requested) by +19 and +1`. After these adjustments, the total authorized amount for "a" was 100.

`80 requested + (19 authorized + 1 authorized) = 100 total authorized.`

Goal: I would like to adjust authorized amounts by bracketed numbers.

```r
library(tidyverse)

## DATA
df <- tribble(
  ~item, ~requested_amount,  ~authorized_amount,
  "a",           80,               "100",  #< Total
  "a",           NA,               "[19]", #< Adjustment from request
  "a",           NA,               "[1]",  #< Adjustment from request 
  "b",           300,              "300",  #< Total (no adjustment)
  "c",           80,                "70",  #< Total
  "c",           NA,              "[-10]"  #< Adjustment from request
              )

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   item  requested_amount    authorized_amount
#>   <chr>            <dbl>    <chr>            
#> 1 a                 80      100              
#> 2 a                 NA      [19]             
#> 3 a                 NA      [1]              
#> 4 b                300      300              
#> 5 c                 80       70               
#> 6 c                 NA      [-10]
```

Desired outcome would treat bracketed amounts as real adjustments:

authorized amount for item `"a" = (80 + 19 + 1) = 100`

```r
#>   item  requested_amount authorized_amount
#>   <chr>            <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1 a                 80               80 #< Together... 
#> 2 a                 NA               19 #< these add...
#> 3 a                 NA                1 #< to 100 for item "a"
#> 4 b                300              300   
#> 5 c                 80               70 
#> 6 c                 NA             - 10
```

Created on 2018-06-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: So why are you adding 19 and 1 but then not subtracting the -10? As a taxpayer this has me really worried!

Comment: Based on the expected output `library(dplyr);library(readr);df %>% mutate(authorized_amount = case_when(!is.na(requested_amount) ~ requested_amount, TRUE ~ parse_number(authorized_amount)))`

Comment: Isn't that a group by sum after the above step

Comment: @akrun, yes, this is the answer. Can you formalize so I can vote you up?

Comment: Please check if the solution I provided below answers

Answer (score 1):

We need to do

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>%
    mutate(authorized_amount = case_when(!is.na(requested_amount) ~ 
                      requested_amount, 
             TRUE ~ parse_number(authorized_amount))
```

Comment: Though parse_number works here, it chokes on negative numbers and is not to be trusted. try `parse_number("[–27,633]")`

Comment: @Nettle Yes, that is an issue.  I thought it is only going to positive numbers.  If that is the case, you can use `as.numeric(str_extract(authorized_amount, "-?[0-9.]+"))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need want the sum of `authorized_amount` summed for each item. One solution is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
df %>% 
  mutate(authorized_amount = readr::parse_number(df$authorized_amount)) %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  summarise(requested_amount = requested_amount[!is.na(requested_amount)],
            authorized_amount = sum(authorized_amount))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  item  requested_amount authorized_amount
  <chr>            <dbl>             <dbl>
1 a                 80.0             120  
2 b                300               300  
3 c                 80.0              60.0
```

Comment: No grouping please. Items must be discrete, with totals adjusted.